# Python crash issue in Fedora 12

Tags: linux, python, fedora-12

How to fix the following issue and what's the underlying problem? Due to this problem, everything that uses `python` is not working.

```
/lib/librt.so.1: symbol
pthread_barrier_wait, version
GLIBC_2.2 not defined in file
libpthread.so.0 with link time
reference

Please install a package which
provides this module, or verify that
the module is installed correctly.     

It's possible that the above module
doesn't match the current version of
Python, which is:
2.6.2 (r262:71600, Aug 21 2009, 12:22:21)  [GCC 4.4.1 20090818 (Red
Hat 4.4.1-6)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with grub2 installation. System reboot solved the problem.